# Unable to build 'yml' file what could be the fault

Tags: heroku, circleci

Can someone help me indent this `.yml` file? Each time I set it I get an error:

```
Unable to parse YAMLmapping values are not allowed here in 'string', line 1, column 17:    version: 2.1orbs:  heroku: circleci/heroku@0.0.1 ...                     ^
```

```
version: 2.1
 orbs:  
  heroku: 
   circleci/heroku@0.0.10
workflows:  
 heroku_deploy:    
jobs: - heroku/deploy-via-git
```

thank you

Comment: What kind of file is this supposed to be? I'm not familiar with `orbs` in a `heroku.yml` file.

Comment: Is this a `.circleci/config.yml` file? Please make sure to include the correct tags and enough context when asking questions. See [ask].

Comment: okay i get you, but basically i was trying to arrange a yaml file so as to carry out auto deploys on heroku production. I now found circleci server hosting to heroku which has all the configuration of yaml using .circleci.yml file. its pretty easy there, but actually arranging yml in its correct order is the issue. hence am asking for a help. i try sending my code in the yml file

Comment: YAML is just a markup language. It doesn't define specific keys or anything like that. So we need to know what _specific_ type of file you're trying to build. _Is_ it for CircleCI? Or for something else?

Comment: exactly Chris, i just use heroku as an entry to the file , actually .circleci.yml. i think it works cause i started a build in heroku and i got this error: i cant post saying too long

Comment: Error messages belong in your _question_, not in comments. Please [edit] and add them.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the element in jobs has to be on a new line and indented?

```
version: 2.1
orbs: 
  heroku: 
    circleci/heroku@0.0.10 
workflows: 
heroku_deploy: 
jobs: 
  - heroku/deploy-via-git
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your line endings aren't being recognized properly. Line 1, column 17 corresponds to the end of this single line, which you believe to be two lines:

```
version: 2.1orbs:
```

Make sure your file is encoded as UTF-8 and uses Unix line endings, then try again.

Comment: thanks Chris, surely get back if work/not

Comment: Hello Chris, i ran into another error i could not post the error from the comment cause of space. i now open it as a new question. when i saw stop shouting at us , which i really don't get that. But please can you check up the question. thanks

Comment: (c) Please reply to comments. This is also important, and also covered on the [ask] page. The reason error messages don't fit in comments is that they're not supposed to. Comments can be deleted at any time, for any reason. Important information like error messages belongs in your _question_. Please edit your question and update it with error messages.